Conditionally Colorize MAUI Devexpress DataGridView Rows
I am working on a .NET MAUI Mobile app and using Devexpress Datagrid on it.
I would like to colorize DataGridView rows if one of the cell value in that confroms a condition.
In example if quantity value in a cell of a row is equal to 0 it should paint the whole row into red and else do nothing.
Tried using CustomCellAppearance bu it works column by column so but i only managed to paint specific cells by using it not the whole row.
Is there any way to achieve that?
ItemsToPickingDataGrid.CustomCellAppearance += ItemsToPickingDataGrid_CustomCellAppearance;

.
.
.

private void ItemsToPickingDataGrid_CustomCellAppearance(object sender, DevExpress.Maui.DataGrid.CustomCellAppearanceEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.FieldName == "PickedQuantity")
        {
            var cellValue = (decimal)ItemsToPickingDataGrid.GetCellValue(e.RowHandle, e.FieldName);
            if (cellValue == 0)
            {
                e.BackgroundColor = Color.FromRgb(50, 50, 50);
            }
        }
    }

Tried using CustomCellAppearance and it didnt work.

Was the ItemsToPickingDataGrid_CustomCellAppearance fired? In addtion, you can open a new ticket on the devexpress support.

@LiyunZhang-MSFT Yea it was fired but becouse it was fired per field, i could only reach one column and its cells. Instead i need to reach the  wholerow of that cell which has cell value of 0 and paint that.

But the CustomCellAppearance event will trigger for every cell, is there anything wrong for the if condition?
